# Crawler : go to the next page, best pratice

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, urllib

I currently write a python crawler, I want to switch to the next page but what is the best pratice ?

Actually it's simple, the end of url is .html?page=1, so I can increment page number but is there a best pratice to do this thing as clean as possible ?

I use urllib, url parse and beautifulSoup

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import urllib
import urlparse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def getURL():
    try:
        fo = open("WebsiteToCrawl", "rw")
        print ok() + "Data to crawl a store in : ", fo.name
    except:
        print fail() + "File doesn't exist, please create WebSiteTOCrawl file for store website     listing"
    line = fo.readlines()
    print ok() + "Return website : %s" % (line)
    fo.close()
    i= 0
    while i<len(line):
        try:
            returnDATA = urllib.urlopen(line[i]).read()
            print ok() + "Handle :" + line[i]            
            handleDATA(returnDATA)
        except:
            print fail() + "Can't open url"
        i += 1

def handleDATA(returnDATA):
try:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(returnDATA)
        for link in soup.find_all('a'):
            urls = link.get('href')
        try:
           print urls
        except:
            print end() + "EOF: All site crawled"

def main():
    useDATA = getURL()
    handleDATA(useDATA)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

NB: I've simpfly the code than the original

Comment: what you have written?? show

Comment: Is it a specific website crawler? Or you are supposed to crawl any site? If any site - there's no correct answer, they are all very different, some don't even have a "next page" concept in them.

Comment: @Rusty, My crawler have a list (about 20 websites), You're right they are all very different but I try to start with generic function and after specific function

Comment: @Hackaholic I've add my code, but it's useless i've write nothing about next page feature.

Comment: I cannot give you a specific answer, but I would find the "next" button on the page and use link from it to go to the next page. This is because altering page manually may include some limitations, such as : on some sites first page is not displayed with a get parameters, some sites will give you a valid, but empty page if you go over the limit, others will give you the last possible page. With the button though, they will probably stop displaying it, or make it go to the same page etc.

Comment: Ok, I'll use soup.select() to retrieve next button link, it's maybe more cleaner than altering page manually as you said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's as straightforward as changing the number in the url, then do that.

However, you should consider how you're going to know when to stop. If the page returns pagination detail at the bottom (e.g. Back 1 2 3 4 5 ... 18 Next) then you could grab the contents of that element and find the 18.

An alternative, albeit slower, would be to parse the pagination links on each page and follow them manually by opening the url directly or using a click method to click next until next no longer appears on the page. I don't use urllib directly but it can be done super easily with Selenium's python bindings (driven by PhantomJS if you need it be headless). You could also do this whole routine with probably an even smaller amount of code using RoboBrowser if you don't have AJAX to deal with.